# Using ssp class complex function giving undefined offset: 0 error

Tags: php, datatables

I am using Datatables v1.10.19 to fetch pipeline data using server side processing.I am using `WHERE` clause in complex function as follows:

```
$where = "recipient='".$recipient."' AND grouped='' GROUP BY id DESC";
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, $where )
);
```

Everything is working fine but when `there are no rows in my table` i am getting the following errors:

> Undefined offset: 0 in C:\MAMP\htdocs\core\ssp.class.php on line 351
>
> Undefined offset: 0 in C:\MAMP\htdocs\core\ssp.class.php on line 359

it should show `no records in table` when there are no rows in database table.

Here is the link to [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)

**PLUS:**

if i remove `GROUP BY id DESC` error gone and datatable shows `no records in table`.

WHAT SHOULD BE CHANGED?NEED SUGGESTIONS.

Comment: As this happens inside the vendor code,.... **Personally**, I'd suggest not using this class. Looks old as heck, like PHP 4 code. Those where params do not look like prepared statements also.

Comment: any modified class?

Comment: You can try to build upon the class and override the method with errors, `class YourSSP extends SSP { }`.

Comment: ssp.class.php doesn't support `GROUP BY` or `JOIN`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39982267/3549014) for a possible solution.

Comment: its complex function supports,check my answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the good news as i was trying to figure out the error ,by placing the following i have solved it.

On line `351` of ssp.class.php by changing the following:

```
$recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];
```

TO

```
if(empty($resFilterLength)){$recordsFiltered="['1','2']";}else{ $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0]; }
```

On line `359` of ssp.class.php by changing the following:

```
$recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];
```

TO

```
if(empty($resTotalLength)){$recordsTotal="['1','2']";}else{ $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0]; }
```

Solves the error.When there were no rows in the table it was giving undefined offset 0 and after changing the above no error and datatable **nicely shows : No data available in table  :)**